# Creating a Event Management System SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have created game in Python with pygame. Now I want to port this game to c++ using SDL2. In the python build of this game there was a sort of event manager system. A class that read the event queue then stored these events in a list so they could be checked multiple times during game loop. The event manager would reset this copy of the event queue and update to the new events. It looks like this:

```
class EventHandler:

    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.event_list = pygame.event.get()
        self.width, self.height = w, h
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height), pygame.RESIZABLE)

    def update(self):
        self.event_list = pygame.event.get()

    def handle(self):
        for event in self.event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                self.width, self.height = event.w, event.h
                self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
        self.update()

    def search(self, eventName): # SEARCH FOR AN EVENT IN THE EVENT QUEUE
        for event in self.event_list:
            if event.type == eventName:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

This a a very simplified version of the event manager class I was using in the python game. I created a copy if the event queue because pygame removes the events from the queue after you have checked the queue for it once. This makes it extremely difficult to detect these event later on in the loop, this is why I created a copy of the event queue to check for events multiple times in the same loop.

How would I be able to copy or add all events needed to a similar data structure of a list such as a vector or std::list in c++. So far this is what I have:

python
class EventHandler
{
public:
bool quit;
SDL_Event event;
SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* render;

```
    int width;
    int height;

    std::string keyEvents;

    //mouse state
    int mouseX, mouseY;
    
    EventHandler()
    {
        //Iniliaze SDL
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
            std::cout << "SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError();
        }
        TTF_Init();
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Fallen Planets", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1024, 1080, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
        if (window == NULL){
            std::cout << "SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError();
            SDL_Quit();
            quit = true;
        }
        render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        if (render == NULL){
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            std::cout << "SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError();
            SDL_Quit();
        }

        //initialise SDL_Image
        IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

        //Initialize quit bool
        quit = false;

        //Get default screen res
        SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);

    }

    void handle(){
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
                SDL_DestroyRenderer(render);
                TTF_Quit();
                SDL_Quit();
                quit = true;
            }
            if (event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED){
                width = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->w;
                height = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->h;

            }
            if (SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN){
                if (event.button.button ==  SDL_BUTTON_LEFT){
                    keyEvents = "MOUSEBUTTON_LEFT";
                }
            }
            //Update Mouse State
            SDL_GetMouseState(&mouseX, &mouseY);
        }
        //SDL_RenderPresent(render);
    }
};
```

Once I have added these events to a vector, I use this code to check the evnts. However I get varying erros from this.

```
    for (std::vector<SDL_Event>::const_iterator i = eventObject.eventList.begin(); i != eventObject.eventList.end(); ++i){
        if (*i == SDL_KEYDOWN){
            std::cout << "key pressed\n";
        }
    }
```

In the above code I get this error: No operator matches const SDL-Event == SDL-EventType. Removing * from the code gives me this error: No operator matches SDL_Event & == SDL_EventType. What would I be doing wrong to check for key events?

Comment: Surely event handler have no business creating window. Anyway, - yes, do as you've described, what seems to be the problem? Make an array or vector if you wish, poll events in a loop, insert event to array, clear array on frame change.

Comment: I have created a vector and added the evnts using vector.push_back() however I cannot find a way to check if a event has occured using the vector in a for loop.

Comment: The same thing you do in python - use `i->type`, not `*i`. Right now you're trying to compare event structure with integer, which is not implemented, hence compile time error. However for me it is hard to imagine comparing event type alone is sufficient; don't you want to add e g. pressed key to comparison?

Comment: I can access the events with event->type in a for loop iterating the event vector if i do not clear the vector each frame. This causes the program to crash due to too many events being dumped into a vector. However clearing the event vector each frame causes the program not to detect any events att all. Is this just from the way I am checking the vector for the event?